# Numpy Array Dimension Issue

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, dimensions

I have two arrays which have different dimensions. I want to bring the latter(india_cases2) to the former(baseline_diag) so that I can plot them easily. I'm unable to plot india_cases.

```
india_daily_cases = pd.read_csv('India_Cases.csv')
india_daily_cases_subset = india_daily_cases.loc[india_daily_cases['t']> 33.,['Daily Confirmed']]
india_cases = india_daily_cases_subset.to_numpy()
india_cases2 = india_cases.T
```

The baseline_diag is an output of function - not sure if providing the whole function code is of any help here. The difference in dimension is as follows:

[image]

The code to plot the graphs is follows:

```
ax.plot(t, india_cases.T, 'r', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label='Actual Observed Cases')
ax.bar(t - 0.2, baseline_onsets, 0.4, label='New Onsets')
ax.bar(t + 0.2, baseline_cases, 0.4, label='New Cases')
```

The error I get is follows:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (47,) and (1, 47)

How do I change the dimenion for india_cases2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of equivalent methods you can use:

```
india_cases2.ravel()
```

```
np.squeeze(india_cases2)
```

```
india_cases2.reshape(-1)
```

Even something like

```
india_cases2.shape = (india_cases2.size,)
```

Alternatively, you could expand `t` with

```
t.reshape(1, -1)
```

Comment: Glad you like it. It's a bit more explicit than ravel

Answer (score 1):

```
india_daily_cases_subset = india_daily_cases.loc[india_daily_cases['t']> 33.,['Daily Confirmed']]
india_cases = india_daily_cases_subset.to_numpy()
india_cases2 = india_cases.T
```

`india_daily_cases_subset`, with this `loc` indexing produces a DataFrame with 1 column.  The `india_cases` is a `(n,1)` array, which with the transpose becomes `(1,n)`.

```
india_daily_cases_subset = india_daily_cases.loc[india_daily_cases['t']> 33.,'Daily Confirmed']
```

without the `[]` around the column selector, the result would be a `pandas.Series`.  Its `to_numpy()` is then a 1d array `(n,)` shape.

In other words, by paying attention to your dataframe indexing, you can get the desired 1d array without the `squeeze/ravel` step.

Comment: Thanks. But I wasn't clear about without using []. Can you explain it a little more. 
I'm sort of coding newbie - so can't get it even if its obvious.

Answer (score 0):

use reshaping by adding desired dimension:

```
baseline_onsets = baseline_onsets[None, :]
```

I do not see `baseline_cases` shape but you might need to do the same for that array.

Answer (score -1):

I would use `numpy.ndarray.reshape`.

I am not sure which shape will be preferable, but you can change the shape as you want by doing `reshape(47)`, `reshape((47,1))` or `reshape((1,47))`.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html?highlight=reshape#numpy.ndarray.reshape

Comment: This is a link only answer

Comment: Sorry, I added how to use.